# Why Modelica doesn't provide a non ideal GearR2T and how to overcome that?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I noticed that Modelica / OpenModelica Connection Editor provides a component called IdealGearR2T

[image: idealGearR2T]

as this name suggests it... it's an ideal component and so efficiciency in both direction is 1 (ie from rotational to translation and from translation to rotational).

I wonder why Modelica doesn't provide a non ideal GearR2T and how to overcome that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a number of steps to build such a model. Basically you need to

- combine e.g. an `idealGearR2T` with an `LossyGear`
- add interfaces (either by adding components or extending an interface) and
- propagate the necessary parameters while setting the ones not to be changed by the user internally.

Doing this you should end up with something like the `LossyR2G` found in the answer to your other question: [How to model a problem with an asynchonous motor, a gearbox, a screw nut system and two discs pierced with holes,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77116841/how-to-model-a-problem-with-an-asynchonous-motor-a-gearbox-a-screw-nut-system/77220983#77220983)

Answer (score 1):

Modelica Standard Library (MSL) which is delivered with all Modelica development environments (OpenModelica, Impact, Dymola etc.) is only meant to provide a selection of the most common and basic models within the most common modelling domains (electrical, mechanical, fluid etc.).

When you create your simulation models you can copy, extend or modify models from MSL to suit your requirements.

You can also suggest the addition of new generic models to the Modelica Association on their [GitHub Issues page](https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaStandardLibrary/issues).

Comment: Maybe a workaround could be to add a lossyGear before idealGearR2T but I don't know how to create my own block which contains lossyGear and idealGearR2T and could be named lossyGearR2T. Any idea?